# Somar segundos a hora - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma coluna com os seguintes valores:

```
945
224
554
487
```

Isso seriam os segundos que preciso somar a uma outra coluna com hora, minutos e segundos

```
12:09:37
23:54:45
10:40:44
11:20:10
```

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma

Pego um valor em segundo e adiciono **00:00:** na frente, exemplo:
**00:00:945** e o excel me retorna **0,0109375** (*Que conta ele faz aqui?*) então pego esse valor e converto para hora e o resultado é **00:03:57**, até ai sem problemas, é só eu somar com a coluna que contem a hora.

O problema é que isso não funciona para mais de **9999** minutos, ele simplesmente não converte **00:00:11000** e e não sei que conta o Excel faz para converter "manualmente"? Ou fazer de uma outra maneira? 
Outro ponto é que tenho que digitar manualmente os 00:00: se eu usar um Concatenar isso fica como texto.

Comment: Apenas uma explicação: o Excel, e muitos outros softwares, tratam a data como dia juliano (o número de dias decorridos a partir de uma determinada data) e o instante do dia como a parte fracionária. Assim um inteiro representa uma data e um timestamp é representado por um número real onde a data é parte inteira e o instante do dia a parte fracionária. Este tipo de representação apresenta inúmeras vantagens nas operações envolvendo datas e para exibição é só escolher o formato mais adequado ao padrão local aonde está sendo utilizado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode fazer da seguinte forma:

1) Converta os segundos para um valor de tempo Excel (sim, é esse o termo):

```
Segundos / 86400
```

2) Depois, na formatação converta ele para um campo do tipo tempo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo um exemplo de como ficaria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É isso ai mesmo, eu tinha descoberto que o Excel fazia por 86400 que é os segundos de 24h. Muito interessante isso.

Answer (score 3):

Basta você dividir o número de segundos que deseja somar pelo total de segundos que corresponde a um dia, que é 86400 segundos (24 horas * 60 minutos * 60 segundos). Você obterá uma fração, então é só somar à hora.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]